# Why the caustic of a circle is the most bright curve in the circle?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

The [caustic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)) of a circle is the envelope of light rays reflected by a circle, which is the most bright curve in the circle. But why?

Here is the picture shows the caustic of a circle:
[image].

Comment: Related : [What's the cause of these limacon figures?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306744/)

Answer (score 2):

This is  because at each point in the caustic curve  pass  two tangent rays almost parallel, thus they interfere constructively, on the other hand, at a point inside the casutic pass two rays  but they can experience constructive interference or destructive, thus a interference pattern emerge. At the level of geometrical optics the rays gives a qualitative description of the intensity pattern, as you can observe in your cup of coffe, where this caustic curve aproximately  emerges. It is important to remark that at the level of the complete optical description, the caustic curve  is near about the maximum of intensity and not exactly on it.